# Composition of analytic functions is analytic in Manifolds

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, analyticity

My problem is in analytic manifolds.According to Cohn's book a function $f$ in  a manifold $M$ is analytic  at $p \in M$ if it can be expressed as a power series of $\sigma(p)=(x_{0})$. That means  $f=f(x)= c_{0}+c_{1}(x-x_{0})+c_{2}(x-x_{0})^{2}+\cdots $.Here $x$ is the image of points in neighborhood of $p$ under the chart $\sigma$

$g$ be an analytic function at $f(p)$. Hence $g = d_{0}+d_{1}(y-y_{0})+d_{2}(y-y_{0})^{2}+ \cdots$ where $\tau(f(p))=(y_{0})$ and  $y$ is the image of points in neighborhood of $f(p)$ under the chart $\tau$ .So $y= f(x)$

Here  $\sigma$ be a chart at $p$ and $\tau$ be a chart at $f(p)$. Composition of charts is again a chart. So I want to show that $g \circ f$ can be expressed as a power series at $\sigma(p)=(x_{0})$.

$g(f(p))= d_{0}+d_{1}(y-y_{0})+d_{2}(y-y_{0})^{2}+ \cdots $.(x)$

Since I am working in analytic manifolds any two charts in $M$ are analytically related.That is same as saying  $\phi = \tau \circ \sigma^{-1}$ can be expressed as a power series at $\sigma(p)$.

If I can claim that $g \circ f$ can be expressed as a power series in $p$ I can complete the proof.

Now what I need is I want to replace  $y$ with $x$.I think I can do it since $f(x)=y$ and then I want to replace $y_{0}=\tau(f(p))$ by  $\sigma(p)=x_{0}$. Then proof will be complete. Can any one help in this step ?
I don't want to use any conditions for analyticity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue you're describing is, but another way of thinking about this is that in charts $\sigma, \tau, \chi$ around $p, f(p), g(f(p))$, respectively, the coordinate representation of $g \circ f$ w.r.t. $\sigma$ and $\chi$ is $\chi \circ g \circ f \circ \sigma^{-1} = (\chi \circ g \circ \tau^{-1}) \circ (\tau \circ f \circ \sigma^{-1})$.

Comment: I will try to elaborate this idea....But in my earlier method I feel I am almost there ..But not sure about some steps...